# Is there anything like GroovyScriptEngine and GroovyClassLoader in Scala?

Tags: scala, groovy, scripting, classloader

I noticed scala is jsr 223 compliant https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-874 ... but is it able to do stuff like GroovyScriptEngine ?  I consider adding a scala scripting support to our product so that developers could write small apps/components/classes that would be loaded from java application (ideally with reloading possibility). I use GroovyScriptEngine for groovy apps/components/classes, but I can't find anything like that in Scala.

Basicaly I'd need to feed it a directory with scala stuff and it would load all scala classes that would be accessible (or at least one) to java app.

Could you please give me some pointers ? This is the only way to use Scala for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Scala Script Engine](http://code.google.com/p/scalascriptengine/)

> This library dynamically compiles scala source files and loads them as
>   classes. Changed scala files will be recompiled and the changed class
>   with be loaded. Multiple source paths are supported as well as
>   compilation class path and class loading class paths (so that the
>   scripts can load extra libraries).
>
> Classpath detection can be automatic (effectively using the classpath
>   of the caller) or manual.
>
> Different compilation and refreshing strategies are provided to suit
>   various purposes.

Comment: How could I miss that :-) I just didn't use exactly that keyword when googling. Thanks